# Enhancement request: Add Base64 session ID generator. Deprecate UuidSessionIdGenerationStrategy

Tags: spring-security, spring-session

Spring Security 3.2 includes [PR 2286](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/pull/2286) for [Issue 11](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/11) to introduce a new feature for overriding session ID generation. This is a good improvement.

My concern is UUID is still the [default strategy here](https://github.com/marcusdacoregio/spring-session/blob/a4e393efb6c2bfb33d8bbabd9dc11a92aaf74b51/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/MapSession.java#L77).

I think it would be useful to introduce a new strategy with higher entropy (i.e. 256-bits random, for 128-bits entropy).

Minimum entropy requirements:

- OWASP: 64-bit (now)
- FIPS 140: 112-bit (now), 128-bit (2030+)
- ANSI: 128-bit (now)

A problem with [UUID Type 4 (random)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) is it generates random 16-bytes/128-bits, but reserved 6 or 7 bits. That leads to only 61-bits or 60.5-bits of entropy, respectively. UUID Type 4 (random) is just too small to meet the lowest entropy recommendation in the above list.

Please deprecate UUID session ID generation. I think creating a new default with 32-bytes random (Base64url-encoded) makes the most sense, because it would satisfy all 3 of the above entropy-recommendations. Note, of the three Base64 encoding options (i.e. standard, url, mime), I think Base64url makes the most sense. My assumption is session IDs are frequently intended to be transmitted via HTTP Cookie headers, and Base64url is compatible with that.

Example:

```
    // not final so developers can extend (e.g. append app-specific info to session IDs)
    public class Base64SessionIdGenerationStrategy  {
        // same Holder class pattern as OpenJDK UUID.java
        private static class Holder {
            static final SecureRandom SECURE_RANDOM = new SecureRandom();
        }

        private static final Base64SessionIdGenerationStrategy DEFAULT_INSTANCE =
                new Base64SessionIdGenerationStrategy(32, Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding());

        private final int numBytes;
        private final Base64.Encoder base64Encoder;
        private Base64SessionIdGenerationStrategy(final int numBytes, final Base64.Encoder base64Encoder) {
            this.numBytes = numBytes;
            this.base64Encoder = base64Encoder;
        }

        @Override
        public String generate() {
            final byte[] bytes = new byte[numBytes];
            Holder.SECURE_RANDOM.nextBytes(bytes);
            return this.base64Encoder.encodeToString(bytes);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the singleton instance of {@link Base64SessionIdGenerationStrategy}.
         * @return the singleton instance of {@link Base64SessionIdGenerationStrategy}
         */
        public static Base64SessionIdGenerationStrategy getInstance() {
            return DEFAULT_INSTANCE;
        }
    }
```

Spring Session 3.2 will provide an option for everyone to override the default UUID strategy. However, I think too many developers will end up doing that to overcome the historical security concerns of using UUID Type 4. Using 32-byte random (Base64url-encoded) as the built-in default session ID strategy would allow most developers to skip having to override the default strategy.

Ideally, I think only those developers that need domain-specific session IDs (e.g. app-info appended to IDs) would need to replace the default session ID generator. And by making the Base64 session ID generator non-final, they could extend the above base class and just override the generate() method.